# Jquery Changing css property based on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to display a div when the window width changes

```
  $(window).resize(function() {
       a(window).width() >= 911  { 
         $(".left-back-btn").css(display: "block");
          }      
 });
```

but it's not working.What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the `a` in `a(window)`?

Comment: Check your console; you likely have a number of errors. Fix those, and maybe find a tutorial on JavaScript, then come back with a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code is kind of a mess. Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 911) { 
        $(".left-back-btn").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $(".left-back-btn").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Comment: Or just `$(".left-back-btn').toggle($(window).width() >= 911);`, or better yet, use [media queries and do it all in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: Thank you so much! I  I can't believe how bad my code was